# Printing the bits of an integer using bitfields and union

Tags: c, union-find

I am given a short int. I need to print the bits of it into two bytes. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union info{
    short z;
    struct data{
        unsigned a:1;
        unsigned b:1;
        unsigned c:1;
        unsigned d:1;
        unsigned e:1;
        unsigned f:1;
        unsigned g:1;
        unsigned h:1;
  };
}t;

union byte{
short n;
struct inside{
    char p:8;
    char q:8;
  };
}v;

int main(void)
{
 short x;

 scanf("%hd",&x);

 v.n=x;

 t.z=v.q;

 printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",t.h,t.g,t.f,t.e,t.d,t.c,t.b,t.a);

 t.z=v.p;

 printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",t.h,t.g,t.f,t.e,t.d,t.c,t.b,t.a);

 return 0;
}
```

My code gives the correct result. But I think that I've written an unnecessarily long code. Moreover, for larger bytes ( like in case of int ) , the process seems to be tiresome. **Can I write the code in a simpler way ?**

Comment: There's no union-find here, only union

Comment: regarding: `printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",t.h,t.g,t.f,t.e,t.d,t.c,t.b,t.a);`   The fields in the union are unsigned, so the use of `%d` is an error.  Suggest `%hu`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Avoid global variables - there's no need for `t` and `v` to exist outside `main()`.

Always check the return value of `scanf()` before using the written values.

Don't assume that `CHAR_BIT` is 8, or that `sizeof (short)` is 2.  Neither of those is portable.

Don't assume a particular ordering of bit fields within a struct - that's entirely compiler-dependent.

Portable code needs a loop to print the bits, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    short x;
    if (scanf("%hi", &x) != 1) {
        fputs("Input error\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    unsigned short v = (unsigned short)x;

    unsigned short mask = -1u;                /* 11111... */
    mask -= (unsigned short)(mask / 2);       /* 10000... */

    while (mask) {
        printf("%d ", (v & mask) != 0);
        mask >>= 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: i actually intend to do it with unions...

Comment: @NehalSamee, you can not do it with `short`,  unions and bit-fields, because no one guaranteed that `short` is 16 bits wide. You should use `uint16_t` instead which is exactly 16 bits wide.

Comment: Should you care about non 2's complement, `(unsigned short)~0;` is a problem.  Suggest `-1u;`

Comment: @chux, I originally had `~(unsigned short)0` there, but didn't like the compiler warning when the result is promoted to `int` before the assignment.  Is `-1u` guaranteed to have all-ones representation?

Comment: @TobySpeight For `unsigned` and narrower unsigned types, `-1u` is all ones.  For wider unsinged types, use a wider constant. `unsigned long long x = -1ull;`.

Comment: The way you're preparing `mask` is fairly awkward. Why not `1 << (8*sizeof(v) - 1)`? That makes it more clear that it's just a 1 in the MSB.

Comment: `1 << (8*sizeof(v) - 1)` is UB when `USHRT_MAX == UINT_MAX` - somewhat common - use `1u`.  `1 << (8*sizeof(v) - 1)` assumes no padding - of course that applies 99.9999+% of the time. A direct setting of the MSBit of `unsigned short mask` is `= USHRT_MAX - USHRT_MAX/2;`

Comment: @Reinderien, I already said that we shouldn't assume a particular value of `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: @eanmos furthermore (and much more important), there is no guarantee regardless the size of the bit-field or its layout.

Comment: @DanM., yeah, you are right. I mentioned it in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

*In addition to @Toby Speight's answer.*

1. **There are only four types allowed for a bit field.** There are the follows: `signed int`, `unsigned int`, `int`, and `_Bool`. So using `char` in this case:

   > ```
   > struct inside{
   >     char p:8;
   >     char q:8;
   > };
   > ```

   is implementation-defined.
2. **Use fixed integer types.** In your code you use `short` the width of which is not well defined. If you want an object with a specific width, you should consider using *fixed integer types* from `<stdint.h>`, such as `uint8_t` or `uint16_t`.
3. **Use an anonymous struct inside the union.** Your code actually is not valid, because `a` is not a member of `t` as well as `p` is not a member of `v`. `a` is member of the inner `data` struct:

   > ```
   > union info{
   >      short z;
   >      struct data{
   >             unsigned a:1;
   >             unsigned b:1;
   >             unsigned c:1;
   >             unsigned d:1;
   >             unsigned e:1;
   >             unsigned f:1;
   >             unsigned g:1;
   >             unsigned h:1;
   >      };
   > }t;
   > ```

   You have to use anonymous structures in order to compile your code.
4. **Bit fields are very implementation defined.** You actually couldn't print bits of integer in a portable way because bit fields are *very* implementation defined. You have to care about a bit field width, about padding inside the structure, about allocation units inside the structure, about width of the integer, about byte ordering, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with most of the suggestions from @TobySpeight, except for the loop variable. Consider:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    short x;
    if (scanf("%hi", &x) != 1) {
        perror("Input error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    unsigned short v = (unsigned short)x;

    for (int i = 8*sizeof(v)-1; i >= 0; i--)
        printf("%u ", 1&(v>>i));
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

You can have a simple integer loop variable. The way this works:

- `i` starts at 15, and decreases to 0
- for every digit, shift the number right by `i`, so that the digit in question is in the least-significant position
- Do a binary-and with 1, and then print the result.

Comment: Minor: `int i = 8*sizeof(v)-1;` assumes no padding in `unsigned short`.  Certainly not a significant  concern.

Comment: I think you misspelt `CHAR_BIT` there: `for (int i = CHAR_BIT * sizeof v - 1;  i >= 0; --i)`